# Como acessar classes no Unity 3D (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos

Estou fazendo um jogo em 3D na Engine Unity, um FPS pra ser mais específico e aproveitando essa experiência pra aprender programação em C#, essa que eu estou tendo na escola.

Porém agora me deparei com um problema, que sei que é de simples solução, mas como não estudei a linguagem aprofundadamente, e só domino o básico de C, não tenho ideia de como resolver.

Eu tenho, pra esse problema, 2 Scripts: O da arma e o do próprio personagem (FPS Controller). Quero, através do script do personagem acessar a classe "Pistol" que é a do meu script da arma, porém, quando declaro:

`private Pistol arma;`

Ele dá o seguinte erro:

> "Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs(46,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Pistol' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Eu entendo o que é esse erro, sei o que está errado, mas não sei como que é o correto.

PS.: Se necessário, posso colocar meu código pra visualização melhor do erro.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, eu conheço apenas o método de instanciar um script com outro, assim você pode acessar um método de Pistol em Player por exemplo.

```
//Pistol
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pistol : MonoBehaviour {

//Instancia Pistol para ficar acessivel a outros Scripts
public static Pistol Instance;
private bool testa = false;

void Awake(){
    Instance = this;
  }
void Start(){
}
public void MetodoTeste(){
    testa = true;
  }
}


//Player
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehavior{

//Instancie Player para poder receber Pistol
public static Player Instance;

void Awake(){
    Instance = this;
  }

void Start () {
    Pistol.Instance.MetodoTeste ();
  }
}
```

Com isso você acessa o 'MetodoTeste' do script Pistol atraves do script Player.
Quando for instanciar um script sempre o declare como public static Nome Instance, assim ele fica acessivel a outros scripts. Lembre de instanciar os dois scripts, Pistol e o Player (que recebera Pistol).

Espero que ajude no que você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você tem os 2 scripts, Arma e Player. Caso eles façam parte do mesmo GameObject (seu player/FPS Controller), você pode pegar o script da seguinte forma:

```
private Pistol arma;
void Start(){
    arma = this.GetComponent<Pistol>();
}
```

Lembrando que você diz: "classe "Pistol" que é a do meu script da arma" A classe e o script tem que ter o mesmo nome, por exemplo: se sua classe chama Pistol, o C# script tem que chamar Pistol também, não Arma.

Agora, se seu script Pistol estiver em outro objeto, por exemplo na própria arma, você pode colocar uma tag nela e no script fazer o seguinte:

```
private Pistol arma;
void Start(){
    arma = GameObject.FindWithTag("arma").GetComponent<Pistol>();
}
```

Acho que isso já ajudará. Você conseguirá referenciar as classes de fora. Boa sorte, abraços